# Can we download a webpage completely with chrome.downloads.download? (Google Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to save a wabpage completely from my Google Chrome extension.
I added `"downloads", "<all_urls>"` permissions and confirmed that the following code save the Google page to `google.html`.

```
  chrome.downloads.download(
            { url: "http://www.google.com",
              filename: "google.html" },
            function (x) { console.log(x); })
```

However, this code only saves the html file.
Stylesheets, scripts and images are not be saved.
I want to save the webpage completely, as if I save the page with the dialog, selecting `Format: Webpage, Complete`.

I looked into the [document](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download) but I couldn't find a way.

So my question is: how can I download a webpage completely from an extension using the api(s) of Google Chrome?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `downloads` API downloads a single resource only. If you want to save a complete web page, then you can first open the web page, then export it as MHTML using [`chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture#method-saveAsMHTML), create a `blob:`-URL for the exported `Blob` using `URL.createObjectURL` and finally save this URL using the [`chrome.downloads.download`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download) API.

The pageCapture API requires a valid tabId. For instance:

```
// Create new tab, wait until it is loaded and save the page
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'http://example.com'
}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function func(tabId, changeInfo) {
        if (tabId == tab.id && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(func);
            savePage(tabId);
        }
    });
});

function savePage(tabId) {
    chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML({
        tabId: tabId
    }, function(blob) {
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // Optional: chrome.tabs.remove(tabId); // to close the tab
        chrome.downloads.download({
            url: url,
            filename: 'whatever.mhtml'
        });
    });
}
```

To try out, put the previous code in `background.js`,
add the permissions to `manifest.json` (as shown below) and reload the extension. Then example.com will be opened, and the web page will be saved as a self-contained [MHTML](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557) file.

```
{
    "name": "Save full web page",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "pageCapture",
        "downloads"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your informative comment. I tried your code and it actually works. Yet the saved file was not in the form I firstly expected, but using mhtml format sounds like a nice idea. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to stackoverflow. Thanks again.

Comment: @rob-w I'm using the `manifest_version=2` in my app. I believe this is required for the chrome *apps*. But the downloads api isn't working on chrome apps. How's that working for you?

Comment: @user3677331 `chrome.downloads` is only available to extensions, not apps. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=274673

Comment: `Error handling response: TypeError: URL.createObjectURL is not a function`
Were there some security changes in Chrome?

Answer (score -1):

No, it does not download for you all files: images, js, css etc. 
You should use tools like [HTTRACK](http://www.httrack.com/).