# Downloading HTML Content from a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

Is there a way I can use the `chrome.downloads` API to download the HTML content of a web page? Basically what I need to do is download a text/HTML file which contains all the content between the `<html>` `</html>` tags, essentially uisng the following line of code:

```
var HTMLContent = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
```

Ideally, I would create a text file which contains the rest of the HTML code and download that file. Can this be done with the chrome.downloads API? Or this there some better alternative?

I excuse myself if this is a completely obvious question... This is the first chrome extension I am writing.

Comment: The `chrome.downloads` API downloads a single resource only. If you want to save a complete web page, try to using `chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML` and follow up this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672190/can-we-download-a-webpage-completely-with-chrome-downloads-download-google-chr?rq=1