# Download a webpage completely (Chrome Extension Manifest v3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

## The Problem :::

- I want to:

  1. Save a wabpage completely as Ctrl+S on google chrome. Using my chrome extension.
  2. Or if there is a library to convert .MHTML file to .zip that contains webpage files in a folder and the webpage as .html. (like what is done when saving the webpage, completely manually)
- I used an old code from this question. [Can we download a webpage completely with chrome.downloads.download? (Google Chrome Extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672190/can-we-download-a-webpage-completely-with-chrome-downloads-download-google-chr)
- But I faced a problem using `URL.createObjectURL()` in the service worker which is undefined Since manifest v3 update.

**This is the answer code from the link above:**

```
// Create new tab, wait until it is loaded and save the page
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'http://example.com'
}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function func(tabId, changeInfo) {
        if (tabId == tab.id && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(func);
            savePage(tabId);
        }
    });
});

function savePage(tabId) {
    chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML({
        tabId: tabId
    }, function(blob) {
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // Optional: chrome.tabs.remove(tabId); // to close the tab
        chrome.downloads.download({
            url: url,
            filename: 'whatever.mhtml'
        });
    });
}
```

---

---

---

**I've tried different approaches here to solve this old code:**

## 1st Try :::

- I added this function `blobToBase64` instead of `URL.createObjectURL()`
- The resulted .MHTML file opens blank webpage. Not like the file saved by chrome browser Ctrl+S (Save As) which opens perfectly.

***service-worker.js:***

```
function saveAsPage(url) {
    //Added code start
    const blobToBase64 = blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
    //Added code end

    function savePage(tabId) {
        chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML({
            tabId: tabId
        }, async function (blob) {

            //var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob); //not working in manifest v3 service worker

            var url = await blobToBase64(blob); //Added line code

            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: url,
                filename: 'whatever.mhtml'
            });

        });
    }

    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: url
    }, function (tab) {

        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function func(tabId, changeInfo) {
            if (tabId == tab.id && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(func);
                savePage(tabId, tab.title);
            }
        });
    });

}
```

---

## # 2nd Try :::

- This time, I tried to send the blob to the content-script from service-worker. To be processed and converted to a url using `URL.createObjectURL()`. But the blob recieved on content-script is corrupted. I think this is due to the large size of it. Its over than 2MB.
- Also, tried to use `saveAs()` from *FileSaver.js* but the blob recieved is already corrupted. When I logged it to the console it is different from the one logged from the service worker console.
- I have an error message on the console of the webpage from the *content-script.js*. The same error type is shown when using `saveAs()` from *FileSaver.js*:

> Error in event handler: TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
> at chrome-extension://ljoihpchcghncfcnfoflfbenhihjdomk/content-script.js:5:34

**Here is the code:**

***service-worker.js:***

```
function saveAsPage(url) {

    async function savePage(tabId, tabTitle) {
        chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML({
            tabId: tabId
        }, async function (blob) {

            var response = await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { blob: blob }); //Added line code

            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: response.url,
                filename: 'whatever.mhtml'
            });

        });
    }

    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: url
    }, function (tab) {

        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function func(tabId, changeInfo) {
            if (tabId == tab.id && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(func);
                savePage(tabId, tab.title);
            }
        });
    });

}
```

***content-script.js:***

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.blob != undefined) {
            //saveAS(request.blob); // From FileSaver.js
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(request.blob);
            sendResponse({ url: url });
        }

    }
);
```

---

- I use this function from service worker console for testing:

```
saveAsPage("https://www.babaloo.gr/product-category/epohiakaeidi/thermansi/aerotherma/");
```

---

- ***manifest.json***

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "icons": {
        "16": "logo/logo-16.png",
        "48": "logo/logo-48.png",
        "128": "logo/logo-128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "pageCapture",
        "downloads",
        "tabs",
        "nativeMessaging"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "FileSaver.js",
                "content-script.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "*://*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: With popup it's easy.
Should I use a service worker?

Comment: I used the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177661/save-html-locally-with-javascript) but still didn't do the save as of google chrome. I would like to be from the service worker if it possible. cause I want it to work from the context menu of the extension as well as the options page. @NorioYamamoto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an implementation using `offscreen`.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "chrome.pageCapture",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "pageCapture",
    "downloads",
    "offscreen"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "hoge"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL("offscreen.html"),
    reasons: ["BLOBS"],
    justification: "justification is required.",
  }, () => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML({ tabId: tabs[0].id }, async (md) => {
        const mdText = await md.text();
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ mdText: mdText }, (response) => {
          const url = response.url;
          chrome.downloads.download({
            url: url,
            filename: "hoge.mhtml"
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

offscreen.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src="offscreen.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

offscreen.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  const md = new Blob([message.mdText], { type: "text/mhtml" });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(md);
  sendResponse({ url: url });
  return true;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete code! Edit: To help anyone who might be confused when implementing this, you have to trigger the save by pressing the extension button (which may well be hidden in the extensions dropdown).